# Javascript Select vector with the greatest number of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, items

I have 4 arrays:

Note: Length of array length is different in any session

```
var Class_A = [8, 11, 3, 9, 11, 16, 16];
var Class_B = [2, 6, 12, 13, 20, 22, 33, 40, 50, 66, 77]; // Greatest length with 11 items,
var Class_C = [10, 14, 19];
var Class_D = [8, 2];
```

I need to select array with greatest number of items, (Class_B)

My expectation is:

```
var major = number major of array.length (in this case Class_B);
```

My code:

```
var major = max(Class_A.length > Class_B.length > Class_C.length > Class_D.length);
```

Edit
An unorthodox solution, from a newbie but it works.

```
var Class_A = [8, 11, 3, 9, 11, 16, 54, 14, 5];
var Class_B = [2, 6, 12, 13, 20, 22, 33, 40, 50, 66, 77, 16, 7]; // Greatest length with 11 items,
var Class_C = [10, 14, 19];
var Class_D = [8, 2];

var Classes = [];
                    Classes.push(Class_A.length) ;
                    Classes.push(Class_B.length) ;
                    Classes.push(Class_C.length) ;
                    Classes.push(Class_D.length) ;

                console.log("Lenght of 4 arrays>"+Classes);
                
                Classes.sort(function(a, b) { // order by major number
                    return a - b;
                });
        
                Classes.reverse(); // reverse array
        
                console.log("Total>"+Classes); // print sort by major number

                console.log("Major>"+Classes[0]); // Works => the magic number that I need
```

Comment: Do realize that `>` results in a boolean. And therefore you are comparing booleans after your first `>`. ... The `Math.max()`  expects its params to be separated by commas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.  Do you want the length of the longest array, the identifier for that array,  or the array itself?

Comment: The line `var major = Class_B;` leads me to believe David wants the longest array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your arrays in an array.

```js
classes = [Class_A, Class_B, Class_C, Class_D];
```

Then, to get the largest one:

```js
classes.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.length > acc.length ? curr : acc);
// => [2, 6, 12, 13, 20, 22, 33, 40, 50, 66, 77]
```

EDIT:

Or, if you want *length* of the largest array:

```js
classes.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.length > acc ? curr.length : acc, 0);
// => 11
```

Comment: OP wants to "select" the array of greatest length

Comment: Yes, and that's what my code will give him.

Comment: Yes i understood. I added the comment to explain

Comment: Is something in my code wrong, yes/no?

Comment: Its perfect. Doubt OP will be able to combine arrays  tho without further assistance.

Comment: OK but I still don't understand what you meant by "OP wants to "select" the array of greatest length."

Comment: Was using OP lingo on "select". Its clear OP has wrong interpretation of `Math.max()`. On "OP" thats my own lingo for "Original Poster".

Comment: Look we are in agreement. I personally wouldnt have been able to code your solution. That it works, we are in agreement.

Comment: @weltschmerz I need to select the largest array and then do in for();

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? And what does "and then do in for();" mean?

Comment: @weltschmerz for (var i=0; i < Class_Major.length; i++) I need major number for bucle

Comment: If you need to get the greatest number from the result of my code above (presumably by `Class_Major` you mean the result of my code, i.e., the array with the most entries), do `Class_Major.reduce((acc, curr) => curr > acc ? curr : acc)`. But that's really a separate question.

Comment: @weltschmerz you script no select major number of array.length, sorry.

Comment: Thanks guys you were very helpful, I wrote a longer solution but it works. Check my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mcvog48/

Comment: No one is checking your code @DavidPumaRios for ungratefulness on help here. Upvoting this answer here tho

Comment: @GetSet I am newbie, I would like the solution to be one line, but I am still learning from you.

Comment: Even "newbies" are grown and can thank ppl. Even "newbies" are human. `I would like the solution to be one line` maybe learn how to code better. Then school us on your own one liners. But, running with help and applying to your code on hack jobs, you not a programmer.

Comment: @GetSet It is not piracy, it is my code but with many more lines, I thought there was some function in javascript as in PHP.

But if I thank you both for your help, the Weltschmerz code I'm still analyzing it and I'm seeing why it doesn't work for me.

You are very kind, thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227436/discussion-between-david-puma-rios-and-getset).

Comment: You "accept" an answer and then want to chat? How about open a new thread / question on further issues? You can provide a link back here